# Use Javascript to randomize background video on page load

Tags: javascript

I'd like to randomly load a video on page load. I have three videos stored locally that I'd like to alternate between but can't seem to get any others except the first to play. I'm very new to Javascript and quite lost on what needs to be fixed...thanks for any help!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var videoStorage = [
      '/vid/background-video-1.mp4',
      '/vid/background-video-2.mp4',
      '/vid/background-video-3.mp4'
    ],
      video = document.querySelector('video'),
      activeVideoUrl = videoStorage[Math.round(Math.random() * (videoStorage.length - 1))];
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="overlay">
    <video autoplay muted loop id="background-video">
      <source src="/vid/background-video-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="/vid/background-video-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="/vid/background-video-3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video></div>
```

Comment: Remove the source HTML elements and set the `src` attribute via JS?

Answer (score 1):

Your `activeVideoUrl` is only set once on page load. Try using `setInterval` to update the value of `activeVideoUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `src` from this `activeVideoUrl` random selected `url`, you can set video `type` and `play`,

You can try this,

```js
var videoStorage = [
    'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
    'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4',
    'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4'
  ],
  video = document.querySelector('#background-video');

// DEFAULT PLAY ON PAGE LOAD
randomPlay();

// RANDOM PLAY FUNCTION
function randomPlay(){
  let activeVideoUrl = videoStorage[
      Math.round(Math.random() * (videoStorage.length - 1))
  ];
  video.type = "video/mp4";
  video.src = activeVideoUrl;
  video.play();
}
```

```html
<button onClick="randomPlay()">Random Play</button>
<div class="overlay">
  <video autoplay muted loop id="background-video" height="150px"></video>
</div>
```

Comment: This is helpful but I'd like to get the video to load and play on page load, so I'm not sure if `randomPlay()` is needed.

Comment: Okay function is for plug and play, its handy, or you can put that code outside from function.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function ()`

````
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      var videoStorage = [
        '/vid/background-video-1.mp4',
        '/vid/background-video-2.mp4',
        '/vid/background-video-3.mp4'
      ],
        video = document.querySelector('#background-video'),
        activeVideoUrl = videoStorage[
          Math.floor(Math.random() * (videoStorage.length))
        ];
      video.type = "video/mp4";
      video.src = activeVideoUrl;
    });
  </script>```
````